# Compile error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm trying to package Qt5 application on Ubuntu 13.04 but I get `error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpulse`

Can you help me to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```